# Cypress Component Runner - Dark Mode

Tags: google-chrome, cypress, darkmode

I am using Cypress 10 and use the interface a lot when building my components, but find the light theme harsh on my eyes, is there a dark mode available?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

### TLDR

Copy and paste the below code in `cypress/support/component.ts`.

```js
//cypress/support/component.ts
import { mount } from 'cypress/react'
import './commands'
declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            mount: typeof mount
        }
    }
}
Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (jsx, options) => {
    assertDarkThemeAttached()
    const result = mount(jsx, options)
    result.then(() => parent.window.document.querySelector('iframe')!.style.display = '')
    return result
})

const assertDarkThemeAttached = () => {
    const parentHead = Cypress.$(parent.window.document.head)
    if (parentHead.find('#cypress-dark').length > 0)
        return
    parentHead.append(`<style type="text/css" id="cypress-dark">\n${style}</style>`)
    parent.window.eval(`
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe')
        if(!iframe) return;
        const cyRoot = iframe.contentDocument.body.querySelector('[data-cy-root]')
        if(!cyRoot) iframe.style.display = 'none'
        // iframe.style.display = cyRoot ? '' : 'none'
    })
    observer.observe(document.body, { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true })
    `)
}
//wrapper for syntax highlighting
const css = (val: any) => val
const style = css`

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

    :root {
        --active-color: #cccccc;
        --background: #222426;
    }
    html, body, #spec-filter, .h-full, .flex, .spec-container, .bg-white{
    background-color: var(--background) !important;
    color: var(--active-color) !important;
    }
}
`
```

### How it works

- `Cypress.Commands.add(...`

  - Override the mount function to make sure the dark theme is attached and then mount. Note it will only 'go dark' once the first test is mounted.
- `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)...`

  - Match your os theme, Comment out the block to have it on all the time.
- `parent.window.eval(...`

  - Disable the iframe while the test is loading or we'll get a horrible white flash. It is enabled again on mount.
- Notes:

  - I've only tested this on the Chrome Component test runner
  - this doesn't effect the tests themselves, thats up to you to make dark mode for your site :)

#### Extra Credit - Dark Chrome Theme

Before installing a new theme the cypress one must be deleted, otherwise it will revert any changes made the next time the browser is opened.

1. Delete the `theme` folder from the [cache](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/advanced-installation#Binary-cache), ie `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\CYPRESS_VERSION\Cypress\resources\app\packages\extension`
2. Open Cypress Chrome
3. Install a dark theme, ie [just black](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/just-black/aghfnjkcakhmadgdomlmlhhaocbkloab)